# Why am I getting NaN and how to use Redux in React Native to add items to a FlatList

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

Hello all I am new to using React Native and Redux and while I feel I am almost wrapping my head around the core concept of redux I am trying to apply it to this application and keep getting lost.
I have yet to incorporate the Flat list efficiently as my MapDispatchToProps is doing visually what I want which is to display the input from the user below when pressing on the the add to list button.

Questions

1st) I cant figure out why I am getting NaN when I add something to the text input?

I have been trying for two days now watching videos and reading documentation

2nd) Any suggestion on how to change my code so that when the user inputs a value it is displayed below via a FlatList?

Really trying to understand what I don't understand so any points would be great.

My Task List component

```
import {
  Text,
  View,
  Button,
  StyleSheet,
  TextInput,
  SafeAreaView,
  FlatList,
} from 'react-native';
import {
  newToDo,
  addToList,
  removeFromList,
  reset,
} from '../redux/actions/index';

const TaskList = ({ todo, history, addToList, removeFromList, reset }) => {
  return (
    <View>
      <SafeAreaView>
        <TextInput
          style={styles.input}
          value={todo}
          placeholder="Enter Value Here"
        />
        <View style={styles.button}>
          <Button
            title="Add Values to List"
            onPress={() => addToList({ todo })}
          />
        </View>
        <View style={styles.button}>
          <Button
            title="RemoveFromList"
            onPress={() => removeFromList({ todo })}
          />
        </View>
        <View style={styles.button}>
          <Button title="Reset" onPress={() => reset()} />
        </View>

        {history.map((x) => (
          <Text
            style={{
              borderWidth: 1,
              borderColor: 'gray',
              borderRadius: 5,
              margin: 10,
              padding: 5,
            }}>
            {x}
          </Text>
        ))}
        <FlatList
          data={newToDo}
          renderItem={newToDo}
          keyExtractor={(item) => item.toDo}
        />
      </SafeAreaView>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  input: {
    padding: 5,
    textAlign: 'center',
    borderWidth: StyleSheet.hairlineWidth * 2,
    borderColor: 'gray',
    borderStyle: 'solid',
    borderRadius: StyleSheet.hairlineWidth * 10,
    marginTop: StyleSheet.hairlineWidth * 20,
    marginBottom: StyleSheet.hairlineWidth * 20,
  },
  button: {
    margin: 5,
  },
});

const MapDispatchToProps = { addToList, removeFromList, reset };
const MapStateToProps = (store) => ({
  list: store.listReducer.newToDo,
  history: store.listReducer.history,
});
export default connect(MapStateToProps, MapDispatchToProps)(TaskList);
```

redux folder
actions

```
import {ADD_TO_LIST, REMOVE_FROM_LIST, RESET_LIST} from '../actionTypes/index';

export const addToList = (newToDo) => {
  return {
    type: ADD_TO_LIST,
    payload: {
      toDo: 'newToDo',
    },
  };
};

export const removeFromList = (newToDo) => {
  return {
    type: REMOVE_FROM_LIST,
    payload: {
      toDo: 'newToDo',
    },
  };
};
export const reset = () => {
  return {
    type: RESET_LIST,
    payload: {
     
    },
  };
};
```

My listReducer

```
  ADD_TO_LIST,
  REMOVE_FROM_LIST,
  RESET_LIST,
} from '../actionTypes/index';

const initialState = {
  history: [],
  list:[],
};
export default function (state = initialState, action) {
  if (action.type == ADD_TO_LIST) {
    return {
      ...state,
      list: state.list - action.payload.toDo,
      history: [...state.history, + action.payload.toDo],
    };
  } else if (action.type == REMOVE_FROM_LIST) {
    return {
      ...state,
      list: state.list - action.payload.toDo,
      history: [...state.history, - action.payload.toDo],
    };
  } else if (action.type == RESET_LIST) {
    return { ...state, list: 0, history: [] };
  }
  return state;
}
```

my Main App

```
import TaskList from './TaskList/index';
import store from './redux/store';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
    <TaskList />
    </Provider>
  )
}

Full project available on expo snacks https://snack.expo.dev/@stephaniebrandon/excited-juice-box
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, why are you trying to minus the action payload in your reducer? If you minus string with an array of course it will return NaN.

```
return {
  ...state,
  list: state.list - action.payload.todo,
  history: [...state.history, -action.payload.newToDo],
};
```

Secondly, you made a typo in your action. There is no such payload called newToDo in the action payload, only toDo. Update your code to the following in your reducer.

```
import {
  ADD_TO_LIST,
  REMOVE_FROM_LIST,
  RESET_LIST,
} from '../actionTypes/index';

const initialState = {
  history: [],
  list:[],
};
export default function (state = initialState, action) {
  if (action.type == ADD_TO_LIST) {
    return {
      ...state,
      list: [...state.list,  action.payload.todo],
      history: [...state.history, action.payload.toDo],
    };
  } else if (action.type == REMOVE_FROM_LIST) {
    return {
      ...state,
      list: [...state.list,  action.payload.todo],
      history: [...state.history, action.payload.toDo],
    };
  } else if (action.type == RESET_LIST) {
    return { ...state, list: 0, history: [] };
  }
  return state;
}
```

Comment: Thank you I see where I went wrong there, I am basing my understanding off of an app we did in class with decrement and increment on a counter.

Comment: It is starting to work how I want except when I applied your code above it is not displaying the value types in the input and just displaying toDo, if you have feedback on that it would be appreciated

Comment: Nevermind I have fixed that part also. I think I am getting it more now thanks